# Upload file with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, file-upload

I want upload the image or file with the tag html but I read that angularJs don't support this tag so the solution is to create a custom directive. So in my page index.html I wrote this code:

```
<body ng-controller="myController">
     <input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
</body>
```

In my js file I write this code:

```
var modulo = angular.module('myApp', []);


modulo.directive('fileModel', function() {
    var modulo = angular.module('myApp', []);
         return {
              restict: 'A',
              link: function (scope, element, attr) {

         }
 }
```

I don't uderstand how I can read the file that the user upload so I don't understand what write in the link function. How can I fix my problem? Is there anybody that help me? Thanks!

Comment: Why you need to use custom directive ? You can listen for a change event on file input and can upload the file right ? More info - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Comment: This probably could help http://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs

Comment: I've used this https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload and its working fine.

Comment: AngularJs don't support the tag input file so I can't use the ng-Change XD

Answer (score 1):

You can not read the file if your browser doesn't supports FileReader API.

Your directive is applied on a file upload control. So, you can listen to its change event. With this change event, you can extract the file object provided in event, emit an event to catch it the controller.

```
app.directive('fileUpload', function () {
return {
    scope: true, 
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        /*Every time you select a file or a multiple files, change event is triggered. 
        So, with this on, we are attaching a listener event to it. This event also contains useful data. Like the array of selected files. 

        So, we iterate over the selected files, and emit an event containing file info.*/
        element.on('change', function (event) {
            var files = event.target.files;                
            for (var i = 0;i<files.length;i++) {

                scope.$emit("fileSelected", { file: files[i] });
            }                                       
        });
    }
};
```

With this code, you are listening to a file upload control's change event. On change, you are emitting an event called `fileSelected`, that you will receive in controller.

```
function DefaultController($scope){
      $scope.files = [];
      $scope.$on('fileSelected', function($event, args){
            $scope.files.push( args.file );
};
```

Please note that, with this code, you are only adding file objects in your scope. You still need to send a request to upload file.

You can use fallowing code taken [from](http://shazwazza.com/post/uploading-files-and-json-data-in-the-same-request-with-angular-js/) with a little bit of correction.

```
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "/Api/PostStuff",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined},
            transformRequest: function (data) {
                var formData = new FormData();

                formData.append("model", angular.toJson(data.model));

                for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {                        
                    formData.append("file" + i, data.files[i]);
                }
                return formData;
            },                
            data: { model: $scope.model, files: $scope.files }
        }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("success!");
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("failed!");
        });
```

Comment: Sorry can you comment this code? 1) element.on('change', function (event)  2) var files = event.target.files;   Thanks

Comment: Added comment on the suggested line.

Comment: If i want upload one file one-by-one, i must write in this way? var file = event.target.files;       scope.$emit("fileSelected", file);

Comment: No. If you want your file to be upload sequentially, it should be AJAX request that must be sent one by one containing one file at a time.

Comment: Sorry I wrote bad...I want send one file and don't send multi-file...the user can replace the file but he/she can send only one file

Comment: You don't have to worry about it. If user selects only one file, array would contain only one entry in it and code will behave accordingly.

Comment: event.target.files is the array containing list of files selected. If only one file is selected, only one file object is present in this array.

Comment: event.target.files isn't the angulaJs...This is javascript? Sorry for many questions but I want understand XD

Comment: Isn't Angular JavaScript ? And we are doing this in angular way. All kind of DOM manipulations should be done in JS.

Consider that if there is not a functionality avaiable in Angular JS but you want it ? In which language you would create it ?

That's right. JavaScript.

Comment: I know...I use the bad word...angularJs is a framework on javaScript...I'm novice...

Comment: Sorry but this code don't work...I use only two piece of code because I want take the file and use in another way...for example I can show the preview in the html page...Where is the problem?

Comment: Sorry why don't it show in tag <img src=".."/> the $scope.files = [0]; ??

Comment: It won't work in that way. Because it is a reference to the file. If You really want to preview the file. 

Consider [this](http://www.codeforest.net/html5-image-upload-resize-and-crop).

Comment: Sorry but what does scope.$emit("fileSelected", { file: files[i] }); do??? I don't understand if work early the directive or controller XD

Comment: Angular JS maintains a hierarchy of scopes. With $scope.$emit(), we are notifying all parent scopes and pass an object containing file object representing the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

You may use already built modules.
There are already many Angular.js modules to perform file uploading:

```
https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/
https://github.com/leon/angular-upload
https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload
https://github.com/uploadcare/angular-uploadcare
```